# Unable to set startup project in Visual Studio 2022 with a .csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to run this example application on my computer but I am having a hard time running it on Visual Studio 2022. I cloned it from Git's website after clicking on open in Visual Studio. I am unable to set the startup project even after scouring through some of the solutions for StackOverflow. I tried editing my launch settings and even adding a startup object to my Projects XML file to no avail.

This is the project in question, https://github.com/halter73/PortExhaustion. Regardless of the solutions, I am unable to set the startup item and end up with 'select a valid startup item.'

Comment: What did you try? Normally, it's just "right click the project and choose 'set as startup project'"

Comment: The StartUp Project isn't usually in the project file.  It's a personal preference that's probably kept in the registry (I'm guessing).

Comment: @LarsTech No, the startup project is stored inside the hidden `.vs` folder.

Comment: It's on my post "right click the project and choose 'set as startup project'" does not seem to be an option for me. And adding it to my startup object does not really seem to do anything. What worked was adding the .csproj manually after downloading the files instead of going directly through GitHub.

Comment: Hi Zarif Rahman, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Sorry about that! I was unaware we could select our answers as the solution to our problem. Thanks again for the reminder!

Comment: Startup projects are usually not in the project file. It may be stored in the registry.

Comment: The StartUp Project is stored in the `.suo` user settings file, hidden inside the `.vs` folder.  As a consequence, it is not possible to have a solution downloaded from a remote repository load into VS with the desired Startup Project already set: the user has to set it manually.  For an altenative solution see https://github.com/SimonCropp/SetStartupProjects

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. Don't try to clone directly from GitHub, it just doesn't seem to add the startup project properly, and then will not let you do anything with the project. The way I solved it was to clone and unzipped the files to a folder and then made Visual Studio open the .csproj file which fixed all of the issues.

Edit: At least for me on Visual Studio 2022